# I have made the lens dirtier than before cleaning it. How can I recover from this?

Tags: lens, cleaning, fujifilm-x-t20

After some testing, I determined that there was some dirt on my 18-50mm lens.

Here is the photo of a white wall with my 18-55mm:

[image]

You can see the settings of above photo here:

[image]

Here is the same wall with a 27mm lens:

[image]

It is 'spotless'.

So I determined that the dirt must rest on the rear end of the 18-55mm lens.

However after cleaning my lens, the situation got worse. Not only did one of the spot remain, it became more prominent; there is also a string of fiber adhered to the surface.

[image]

I used the following to clean my lens.

[image]

How can I recover from this?

Comment: When you tested the shots, did you stop down to f/22?

Comment: Yes for the 18-55mm. Attached the photo metadata to the question.

Comment: But not the 27? It looks like sensor dust to me...and wide apertures blur the dust and make it harder to see...so you’d have to test again with the 27 but at f/22 to confirm. Dust on a lens...scratches even...can be pretty bad before it starts to impact image quality. I’m betting you just have some dust on the sensor.

Comment: The 27mm does not have an aperture ring like the 18-50mm, so I am not sure how to set it.

Comment: @AnthonyKong You should be able to set aperture on lenses without aperture ring by scrolling the thumb wheel.

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is the result of dust on your sensor, not on the lens.

Most modern Digital SLR and mirrorless cameras have a sensor self cleaning mode. Check your manual for instructions on how to use the self cleaning system, or how to manually clean the sensor yourself using a blower or other methods.

You can also have a camera shop clean your sensor.